# How to convert TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE to GMT TIMESTAMP in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a field which is of TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE(Oracle SQL) type and it has data of different time zones. Example:

```
25-JUN-16 09.15.00.000000000 AM +08:00
30-JUL-16 10.00.00.000000000 AM +03:00
```

Now we have to convert each timestamp(of different time zones) in the table to a timestamp of GMT time zone. These updates should be done through a procedure.

We tried to use SYS_EXTRACT_UTC function, but we are getting the error:

> 1843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"

Query:

```
select sys_extract_utc(TIMESTAMP '30-JUL-16 10.00.00.000000000 AM +03:00') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

**use below query**

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2012-07-02 10:00:00-04' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT';
```

result

### ------------------------------

2012-07-02 14:00:00
(1 row)

---

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2012-07-02 14:00:00-00' AT TIME ZONE 'EDT';
```

result

### ------------------------------

2012-07-02 10:00:00
(1 row)